# How to pass string and context to AsyncTask method and call the method with the parameters

Tags: java, asynchronous

this is the Async method call creatAccount

```
 public static void multidata(Context context, ContactMaster cm) throws IOException, JSONException {
   ContactMaster cm = db.findCRMContacts(regPhone);
   final String CompanyName = cm.getCompanyName();
   new createAccount(String CompanyName,Context context).execute();
}
```

this is the method definition for createAccount with doInBackground using the parameters

```
 private  class createAccount extends AsyncTask<String, Context, String> {
  protected  String doInBackground(String companyName,Context context){
  // api call to create account
}
}
```

trying the above code - shows erroe on method call

Comment: `   new createAccount(String CompanyName,Context context).execute();` should be `   new createAccount(CompanyName,context).execute();`. You do not specify types when calling a method.